# Language.Haskell.Interpreter: is this the right tool for the job at hand?

Tags: haskell, eval, interpreter

I have a little toy semantics for natural language, with words like:

```
ran :: String -> Bool
ran = (`elem` ["Bart", "Homer", "Marge"])
```

and:

```
bart :: String
bart = "Bart"
```

So for example, I can have `(ran bart) :: Bool`, and so on.

I want to write a parser which, for example takes the string `"Bart ran"` and returns `True`. I'd probably use Parsec for this.

However, the problem is being able to call functions via strings. E.g. getting from `"ran"` to the function `ran`. For this, I thought [`Language.Haskell.Interpreter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint)'s `interpret` function might be appropriate.

So my questions are:

1. Is this a sensible way to do what I want to do?
2. If so, why doesn't the following work, entered into GHCi, given a module called `Grammar.hs` in the same directory with `ran` defined as above:

   ```
   let a = runInterpreter $ do
             loadModules ["Grammar"]
             setImports ["Prelude"]
             interpret "ran" (as :: String -> Bool)
   let b = do
             x <- a
             return $ x <*> pure "John"
   b
   ```

I get the error:

```
"Left (WontCompile [GhcError {errMsg = "<interactive>:2:1:\n    Not in scope: \8216ran\8217\n    Perhaps you meant \8216tan\8217 (imported from Prelude)"}])"
```

which suggests that the import isn't working, and indeed, if I try something similar with a Prelude function, everything works.

3. Why do I get the following type error (among many others) if I try to compile the same code as in Q2, (minus the `let`):

> No instance for `MonadIO m0` arising from a use of `runInterpreter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for #2, you need to add `"Grammar"` to the `setImports` list as well:

```
runInterpreter $ do
    loadModules ["HintDefs"]
    setImports ["Prelude", "HintDefs"]
    interpret "ran" (as :: String -> Bool)
```

As for #3, it is because [`runInterpreter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.6.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v:runInterpreter) is monomorphic in the choice of monad to run it in:

> ```
> runInterpreter :: (MonadIO m, MonadMask m) 
>                => InterpreterT m a 
>                -> m (Either InterpreterError a)
> ```

So you'll need to choose a particular `m` by running it in e.g. `IO`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    ran <- runInterpreter $ do
        loadModules ["HintDefs"]
        setImports ["Prelude", "HintDefs"]
        interpret "ran" (as :: String -> Bool)
    print $ ran <*> pure "John"
```

Now, as for #1, I am not convinced you need something as stupidly powerful as HInt here. You could just maintain a dictionary of `String -> Bool` functions keyed by a `String` key, something simple like a `Map String (String -> Bool)`, and then use that to look up `ran` etc.